# Ignore SSL certificate in Android *for an existing app*

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

Not gonna go into details about what I'm attempting to achieve here (which is not really about writing programs), but when using an existing Android app, I hit a wall which translates to the following in ADB logcat:

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

It seems like the app somehow won't trust the remote server, so I searched for solutions to bypass this, but as far as what I've seen, the results are all about how to work around it *when you're developing*, i.e. when you have the source code of the app itself. The situation here is that I'm never going to have the privilege to get the source for the app, so what I'm looking for is a solution that can work around it *for an existing app*. An app/plugin to do this is okay, or even a way to reverse engineer the APK I have and add in the stuff I need - you say it, people upvote it, and I go learn it.

Thanks for your time for reading through a newbie's first question here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
>
> It seems like the app somehow won't trust the remote server,...

No peer certificate means that the server did not send a certificate at all. So the usual methods of ignoring the result of the certificate validation will not help, because if there is no certificate there is no validation. Since the application seem to expect a certificate this looks more like a misconfigured server.

Comment: Quick answer, sir! However, just as I can't touch the app's source, the server is also not under my control, so even if it's really a misconfigured server, I don't really have anything to do on my side, is this so? Or is there any other way that simply tells Android to ignore all such errors?

Comment: That depends on the app if it will be possible and how it can be done. You might try to use a man-in-the-middle proxy which then deals with the problem (will not work if the app uses certificate pinning). If this will not work you probably have to decompile the app and change the code.